# Radio Button in one radio group in 2 horizontal line

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

[image]

i try to set 4 radio button in one Radio group in 2 lines, but problem is that when i take linear layout with horizontal orientation then radio group functionality not work . All Radio buttons select . At a time only one button should be select.

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/r1"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/lbl1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/r2"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/lbl2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/r3"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/lbl3" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/r4"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/lbl4" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of your layout, please?

Comment: i put one image over here here , i can set layout this way but radio group functionality not work after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know if you still need another option but you can "force" a second line using this:

1. set the *orientation* of the RadioGroup *horizontal*
2. second set the  same *marginTop* in the radioButtons in the same "line"
3. third set a negative *marginStart* on the first element of every (2 and forward) 
   this will mark the star of each line and the other elements will follow

here is an example of this:

```
 <RadioGroup
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:id="@+id/Rgroup">

 <RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/r1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/lbl1" />

   <RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/r2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/lbl2" />

  <RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/r3"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="-180dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="40dp" 
   android:text="@string/lbl3" />

  <RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/r4"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="40dp" 
   android:text="@string/lbl4" />

   </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

RadioGroup does not currently allow nested layouts. (See AOSP issue #8952 for more details)

Because of this, RadioButtons must be direct children of the parent RadioGroup.

That being the case, and noting that RadioGroup extends LinearLayout, I think you're stuck with having to list all of your radio buttons in one row, or in one column.

By the way, there is nothing to stop you from creating your own version of RadioGroup that extends from something more flexible like RelativeLayout.  You could start with the code in RadioGroup and adapt it to suit your needs.

Comment: then how can handle functionality like select one option from given four options?

Comment: You can programmatically set up this mutually exclusive scoping by using setOnCheckedChangeListeners for each radio button in your group, and when you see a check change, uncheck all the others in your logical group.

Answer (score -1):

To make RadioGroup to have columns, just add GridLayout inside it and change  **android:columnCount** parameter.
However you have to override all radio button's OnCheckedChangeListeners, because when you put RadioButtons in GridLayout they are not group anymore.

```
<RadioGroup

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="3">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbtn_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbtn_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        .....


        </GridLayout>

    </RadioGroup>
```